# Почему не отображается QPushButton в PyQt5?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, gui, pyqt

Внутри своего класса я создаю окно:

```py
    def create_GUI(self):
        self.root_window = QWidget()
        self.root_window.setWindowTitle('''Mint Player''')
        self.root_window.setFixedSize(400, 200)
        self.root_window.setWindowIcon(QIcon('''headphone.ico'''))
        self.root_window.show()
```

и кнопку:

```py
        self.next_button = QPushButton('Some text', self.root_window)
        self.next_button.setCheckable(True)
        self.next_button.move(10, 10)
```

Только вот кнопка не отображается, хотя делаю всё вроде бы правильно. 
В чём дело?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас есть два пути, чтобы показать кнопку:

Первый, покажите ваше второе окно после того как оно полностью сформировано и это правильный вариант;

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)

        self.create_GUI()

    def create_GUI(self):
        self.root_window = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.root_window.setWindowTitle('''Mint Player''')
        self.root_window.setFixedSize(400, 200)
        self.root_window.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon("im.png"))

#        self.root_window.show()                                               # ---

        self.next_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Some text', self.root_window)
        self.next_button.setCheckable(True)
        self.next_button.move(10, 10)

        self.root_window.show()                                                # +++

if __name__ == "__main__":        
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

Второй, если вы показали окно, а потом добавили в него дочерние виджеты, то их также надо показать:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)

        self.create_GUI()

    def create_GUI(self):
        self.root_window = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.root_window.setWindowTitle('''Mint Player''')
        self.root_window.setFixedSize(400, 200)
        self.root_window.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon("im.png"))
        self.root_window.show()                                              

        self.next_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Some text', self.root_window)
        self.next_button.setCheckable(True)
        self.next_button.move(10, 10)
        self.next_button.show()                                                 # +++

if __name__ == "__main__":        
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]